# Snakemake - MissingInputException

Tags: snakemake

My snakemake pipeline containing 31 rules is driving me crazy. It's a mapping and snp calling pipeline that uses BWA and HaplotypeCaller among others. I have created a conda environment for each rule, depending on the program used. My code is quite long and can be seen if needed at this address : https://github.com/ltalignani/SHAVE1

Concretely, when I want to build the DAG, snakemake tells me that the haplotype_caller rule doesn't have the reference genome as input. But it is in the file. Here is the concerned code:

```
rule haplotype_caller_gvcf:
# Aim: Call germline SNPs and indels via local re-assembly of haplotypes
# Use: gatk --java-options '-Xmx{MEM_GB}g' HaplotypeCaller  \
#           -R Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta \
#           -I input.bam \
#           -O output.g.vcf.gz \
#           -ERC GVCF                                                     # Essential to GenotypeGVCFs: produce genotype likelihoods
message:
    "HaplotypeCaller calling SNVs and Indels for {wildcards.sample} sample ({wildcards.aligner}-{wildcards.mincov})"
conda:
    GATK4
input:
    refpath = REFPATH,
    reference = REFERENCE,
    bam = "results/04_Variants/{sample}_{aligner}_{mincov}X_indel-qual.bam"                                                           
output:
    gvcf="results/04_Variants/haplotypecaller/{sample}_{aligner}_{mincov}X_variant-call.g.vcf"
log:
    "results/11_Reports/haplotypecaller/{sample}_{aligner}_{mincov}X_variant-call.log"               # optional
resources:
    mem_gb= MEM_GB,
shell:
    "gatk HaplotypeCaller " # --java-options '-Xmx{resources.mem_gb}g'
    "-R {input.refpath}{input.reference} "
    "-I {input.bam} "
    "-O {output.gvcf} "
    "-ERC GVCF"                                         # Essential to GenotypeGVCFs: produce genotype likelihoods
```

With the REFPATH and REFERENCE variables defined as follows in the snakefile header:

`REFPATH = config["consensus"]["path"]               # Path to reference genome`
`REFERENCE = config["consensus"]["reference"]        # Genome reference sequence, in fasta format`

And the config file in .yaml is like this:

`consensus:`

`reference: "GCA_018104305.1_AalbF3_genomic.fasta"`

`path: "resources/genomes/" # Path to genome reference`

When I ask for the DAG :

```
snakemake -s workflow/rules/shave.smk --dag | dot -Tpng > test.png
```

I get this error:

```
`MissingInputException in line 247 of /Users/loic/snakemake/short-read-alignment-vector-pipeline/workflow/rules/shave.smk:`
```

`Missing input files for rule haplotype_caller_gvcf:`

`GCA_018104305.1_AalbF3_genomic.fasta`

Here is the structure of the snakemake:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYQtf.png)

also tried to use snakemake --lint but the output was OK.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your Github, and the folder `resources/genomes/` only contains a file `GCA_018104305.1_AalbF3_genomic.fasta.fai`. Have you tried renaming this file to the expected input name `GCA_018104305.1_AalbF3_genomic.fasta`, e.g. get rid of the `.fai` extension?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer,
The fasta is 1.47 GB. That's why it's not in the resources/genomes folder.
The .fai is the fasta index, necessary for some programs like GATK.